# Stack Overflow data dump & table information

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, data-dump

I am trying to find the Stack Overflow data dump, and if there any existing code to actually put the data into SQL tables. Also where can I find the description of the tables that are available in the data dump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema description is changing sometimes, with improvements to the site, and can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/186121). You can download [the latest version at the time of writing](http://media10.simplex.tv/content/xtendx/stu/stackoverflow/stack-exchange-2011-09.tar) or an [older version](http://media10.simplex.tv/content/xtendx/stu/stackoverflow/).

Comment: The latest version, as of Dec 2012 is from Sept 2011? So much for the tri-monthly, or even annual release schedule. Has SE decided to give up Creative Commons?

Comment: At the time of writing, [the lastest version of the data dump is from 2012-08-17](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump/contents).

Comment: @Cerin: see previous.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Thank you. Frustratingly, that page was not linked anywhere in the [primary](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/) [pages](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/) returned by Google on the topic.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange has an API through which you can access its data. It's better to use the API to do what you are trying as the internal structure are often changed as per requirement. Go for

> http://api.stackexchange.com

And, if you want to explore the data and run queries on it, go for:

> http://data.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Shree, Thanks Prabhu :)